# How we can add custom Aggregate Function in grails criteria projection?

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

i am trying impelement my query, using criteria. in my query i have min, max, count, and Oracle median function.
**How can I create my median function and call it in creteria projection part?**

```
def getTotalResult() {
    def map= [:]
    def result = Freight.createCriteria()
    def freightResults = result.list {
        projections {
            groupProperty "polCode" // 0
            groupProperty "podCode" // 1
            groupProperty "ctnSize" // 2
            groupProperty "carNam"  // 3
            groupProperty "curCode" // 4
            groupProperty "motCode" // 5
            count()
            min('unitValue')
            max('unitValue')
            med('unitValue')        // HOW CREATE THIS CUSTOM FUNCTION 
        }
    }
    freightResults.each {
        map.put(it[6], it)
    }
    return map
}
```

Comment: I am trying create  med(String propertyName) method, but in this case i only call local function, not criteria's function like min, max sum , etc

Comment: Hey you can for sure do that. I guess you should play around meta-programming and try creating a function there for your med

Comment: you may play around HibernateCriteriaBuilder and Projections classes

Comment: **can you explain more about your suggestion?**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I wanted to add to `createCriteria` the `full-text` feature of mysql so I took a look to [`RLikeExpression.java`](https://github.com/grails/gorm-hibernate5/blob/9c9da0e90c22382967c014a165612ed1786f1ab3/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5/src/main/groovy/grails/orm/RlikeExpression.java) and implemeted the fulltext, first I created the `Criterion`

```
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaQuery;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion;
import org.hibernate.criterion.MatchMode;
import org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.TypedValue;

public class MysqlMatchAgainstExpression implements Criterion {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2143299180509579568L;

    private final String searchColumns;
    private final String searchValue;

    public MysqlMatchAgainstExpression(String searchColumns, Object searchValue) {
        this.searchColumns = searchColumns;
        this.searchValue = searchValue;
    }

    public String toSqlString(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) throws HibernateException {
        Dialect dialect = criteriaQuery.getFactory().getDialect();

        def searchColumnsField = this.searchColumns.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").split(",").collect{ it ->
            def columns = criteriaQuery.getColumnsUsingProjection(criteria, it.trim());
            return columns[0]
        }.join(", ")
        return "match (${searchColumnsField}) against (? in boolean mode)"
    }

    public TypedValue[] getTypedValues(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) throws HibernateException {
        //return new TypedValue[] { criteriaQuery.getTypedValue(criteria, searchColumns, searchValue.toString().toLowerCase()) };
        def property = this.searchColumns.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").split(",").first();
        println property
        return [ criteriaQuery.getTypedValue(criteria, property, searchValue.toString()) ] as TypedValue[];
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "match ${searchColumns} against ('${searchValue}' in boolean mode)";
    }
}
```

Then I added to `HibernateCriteriaBuilder` the `method` fullTextSearch

```
void doWithDynamicMethods() {
    grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.metaClass.fullTextSearch= {searchColumns, searchValue->
        addToCriteria(new MysqlMatchAgainstExpression(searchColumns, searchValue));
        return this;
    }
}
```

I can use it like this...

```
User.createCriteria().list{
    fullTextSearch "(name, addressLine1, addressLine2)", 'mordor'
}.each{it ->
    println it.name
}
```

I know it doesn't answer the question per se,and it's a criterion not a projection, but I hope that after this it helps you to create the method `med`

Ok, I look for how are made the projections and it seems is like this

```
public class MedianProjection extends AggregateProjection {
    public MedianProjection (String propertyName) {
        super( "MEDIAN", propertyName );
    }
}
```

then added to `HibernateCriteriaBuilder`

```
void doWithDynamicMethods() {
    grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.metaClass.med= {propertyName->
        def proj = new MedianProjection (calculatePropertyName(propertyName));

        addProjectionToList(proj, alias);

        return this;
    }
}
```

and let's cross the fingers and hope it works :)

```
def freightResults = result.list {
    projections {
        groupProperty "polCode" // 0
        groupProperty "podCode" // 1
        groupProperty "ctnSize" // 2
        groupProperty "carNam"  // 3
        groupProperty "curCode" // 4
        groupProperty "motCode" // 5
        count()
        min('unitValue')
        max('unitValue')
        med('unitValue')        // HOW CREATE THIS CUSTOM FUNCTION 
    }
}
```